# Virtual interface gets static IP, actual interface doesn't?

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig

I have a server running Debian 6 with two static IP addresses assigned: eth0 and eth0:1 (virtual interface of eth0). On boot, both should get their assigned IPs...but eth0 does not.

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.9.171
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.9.0
    broadcast 192.168.9.255
    gateway 192.168.9.23
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 192.168.9.23 192.168.9.41
    dns-search ourdomain.local
auto eth0:1
```

`iface eth0:1 inet static   address 192.168.9.11   netmask 255.255.255.0   network 192.168.9.0   broadcast 192.168.9.255   gateway 192.168.9.23   # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed   dns-nameservers 192.168.9.23 192.168.9.41   dns-search ourdomain.local`

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:79:95:a4:e7
          inet6 addr: fe80::212:79ff:fe95:a4e7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10378 errors:0 dropped:8 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1634657 (1.5 MiB)  TX bytes:453396 (442.7 KiB)
          Interrupt:17

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:79:95:a4:e7
          inet addr:192.168.9.11  Bcast:192.168.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:17

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:550 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:550 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:189714 (185.2 KiB)  TX bytes:189714 (185.2 KiB)
```

Any ideas? The only way it'll get an IP is if I do `ifconfig eth0 192.168.9.171`.

Comment: Do you have the `auto eth0` line in your `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: Nope. I'll probably facepalm if that was the only issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your problem, by default debian comes with: allow-hotplug eth0

Check out the official documentation here:
http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_basic_syntax_of_etc_network_interfaces